# Extracting subgraph and edge portions based on spatial coordinates

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Suppose I have a graph:

```
RandomSeed[1000];
g = RandomGraph[{20, 50},
   VertexLabels -> "Name"];
```

which has been laid out or embedded by some automatic specification (i.e., I did not place the vertexes explicitly).  Suppose I'm interested in a *spatial region* of this graph, for instance as outlined in red here:

```
Show[g, 
   Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None], 
   Rectangle[{1.2, 0.2}, {2.2, 1.2}]}]]
```

[image]

I'd like to "zoom in" and extract the subgraph defined by the vertexes within the defined bounding box *and* the edges, some of which extend outside the region.

[image]

I can select the vertex coordinates within the bounding box, for instance:

```
Select[(VertexCoordinates /. AbsoluteOptions[g, VertexCoordinates]), 
 1.2 < #[[1]] < 2.2 && 0.2 < #[[2]] < 1.2 &]
```

but I do not see how to extract the vertex identities and the edges (and partial edges) within the bounding box.

I would like to extract this information in Graph form so I can re-render the portion of the graph, possibly re-label or re-color vertexes, and such.  A pure "image based" solution (extracting the image region) is not acceptable for my application.  Moreover, I need to retain the spatial locations of the enclosed vertexes so I can scale and replot such that the layout is the same (only larger).  In short, cannot merely extract the vertexes and link identities and re-layout the subgraph information with a different embedding.

I don't mind having a list of the full edges that traverse the region; I can plot the resulting graph and then spatially truncate it by `Show[ mySubGraphInformation, {{xL, xH},{yL, yH}}]`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 3:** For an arbitrary cropping region, for example

```
rp = RandomPoint[Rectangle @@ transpose[MinMax /@ Transpose[GraphEmbedding[g]]], 4];
region = BoundingRegion[rp, "FastEllipse"];
```

it is slow, but we get

[image]

**Update 2:** Rolling all steps into a function that returns a list of edges and vertices that intersect the input rectangle and a list of graphics primitives (points and portions of edges that lie in the input rectangle):

```
ClearAll[cropG]
cropG[g_, region_] := Module[{cTov = Thread[GraphEmbedding[g] -> VertexList[g]], 
 prims = Cases[Normal[Show[g][[1]]], _Arrow | _Disk, {0, ∞}] /. 
     {Disk[a_, _] :> Point[a],
      Arrow[BezierCurve[b_, ___], _] :> Line[BezierFunction[b] /@ Subdivide[0, 1, 100]],
      Arrow[c_, _] :> Line[c]}, 
 primsToParts = {Line[a_] :> (UndirectedEdge @@ a[[{1, -1}]]), Point[b_] :> b}}, 
 Transpose @ DeleteCases[{Replace[#, Join[cTov, primsToParts ], {0, ∞}], 
       RegionIntersection[region, #]} & /@ prims, {_, _EmptyRegion}]]
```

Examples:

```
cropG[g, rect][[1]]
```

> {1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 9, 4 <-> 12, 4 <-> 15, 
>    4 <-> 16, 4 <-> 19, 5 <-> 11, 5 <-> 19, 5 <-> 20, 11 <-> 20, 
>    12 <-> 20, 15 <-> 20, 4, 5}

```
cropG[g2, rect2][[1]]
```

> {1 <-> 15, 1 <-> 19, 1 <-> 20, 2 <-> 15, 2 <-> 19, 3 <-> 17, 3 <-> 19,
>     3 <-> 20, 4 <-> 15, 4 <-> 19, 5 <-> 11, 5 <-> 19, 5 <-> 20, 
>    6 <-> 17, 7 <-> 17, 8 <-> 20, 10 <-> 14, 10 <-> 19, 11 <-> 12, 
>    11 <-> 13, 11 <-> 20, 12 <-> 20, 13 <-> 20, 14 <-> 15, 14 <-> 20, 
>    15 <-> 20, 16 <-> 19, 17 <-> 20, 11, 15, 17, 19, 20}

**Update:** Getting all edges, edge portions and vertices that intersect the rectangle. (Borrowing/stealing the `BezierFunction` idea from @Carl's answer to convert `BezierCurve`s to `Line`s)

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = RandomGraph[{20, 50}, VertexLabels->"Name"];
rect = Rectangle[{1.2, 0.2}, {2.2, 1.2}];
Show[g, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None],    rect}]]
```

[image]

```
vcToVertex = PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates] -> # & /@VertexList[g];

primitives = Cases[Normal[Show[g]], _Arrow|_Disk,{0, Infinity}] /.
   {Disk[a_, _] :> Point[a], 
   Arrow[BezierCurve[x_,___],_] :> Line[BezierFunction[x]/@Subdivide[0, 1, 100]], 
   Arrow[y_,_]:>Line[y]};

primitivesInRectangle = DeleteCases[{Replace[#, Join[vcToVertex, 
 {Line[z_] :> (UndirectedEdge @@ z[[{1,-1}]]), Point[p_]:>p}], {0, ∞}], 
  RegionIntersection[rect, #]}& /@ primitives, {_,_EmptyRegion}];

portionsInRectangle = primitivesInRectangle[[All, 2]];
edgesAndVertices = primitivesInRectangle[[All, 1]]
```

> {1 <-> 5, 2 <-> 5, 3 <-> 5, 4 <-> 5, 4 <-> 9, 4 <-> 12, 4 <-> 15,
>        4 <-> 16, 4 <-> 19, 5 <-> 11, 5 <-> 19, 5 <-> 20, 11 <-> 20, 12 <-> 20, 15 <-> 20,
>        4, 5}

```
Show[g, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None],  rect, Thick, 
   PointSize[.03], Blue, primitivesInRectangle[[All, 2]]}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[HighlightGraph[g, Style[#, Thick,Orange]& /@ edgesAndVertices], 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[], rect}]]
```

[image]

An example with curved edges:

```
SeedRandom[1];
g2 = RandomGraph[{20, 50}, VertexLabels->"Name", GraphLayout->"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"];
rect2 = Rectangle[{-5,-.5}, {.5, 2.5}];
Show[g2, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None],  rect2}]]
```

[image]

`edgesAndVertices`:

> {1 <-> 15, 1 <-> 19, 1 <-> 20, 2 <-> 15, 2 <-> 19, 3 <-> 17, 3 <-> 19,
>     3 <-> 20, 4 <-> 15, 4 <-> 19, 5 <-> 11, 5 <-> 19, 5 <-> 20,
>    6 <-> 17, 7 <-> 17, 8 <-> 20, 10 <-> 14, 10 <-> 19, 11 <-> 12,
>    11 <-> 13, 11 <-> 20, 12 <-> 20, 13 <-> 20, 14 <-> 15, 14 <-> 20,
>    15 <-> 20, 16 <-> 19, 17 <-> 20,
>    11, 15, 17, 19, 20}

```
Show[g2, Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None],  rect2, Thick, 
   PointSize[.02], Blue, primitivesInRectangle[[All, 2]]}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
Show[HighlightGraph[g2, Style[#, Orange, Thick]& /@ edgesAndVertices], 
 Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None],  rect2}], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

A partial answer for the easier part of the requirements:

```
rect = Rectangle[{1.2, 0.2}, {2.2, 1.2}];
verticeInRect = Select[VertexList[g], 
   RegionMember[rect, PropertyValue[{g, #}, VertexCoordinates]] &];

g2 = Show[HighlightGraph[g, verticeInRect], 
  Graphics[{EdgeForm[Red], FaceForm[None], rect}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[g2, PlotRange->(Transpose[{##}]&@@rect), ImageSize->300]
```

[image]

Note: `Show` produces a `Graphics` object. To zoom on part of `g` without turning `g` into `Graphics`, you can use

```
SetProperty[g, {PlotRange -> (Transpose[{##}] & @@ rect),  ImageSize -> 300}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice (+1).  This may be enough for an *accept*... let me play around with it for a while first.  Wait... how did your `RegionMember` extract the portion of the edge linking two vertices both *outside* the bounding box?

Comment: @David, `RegionMember` checks just the vertex coordinates. Capturing edges requires more effort ,that is, this _is_ a partial answer:)

Comment: @David, hope the updated version is complete.

Comment: kglr:  Bravo! A *tour de force*.  Thanks *so* much.

Comment: David, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Answer (score 2):

It's a very good idea to choose a random seed so that others can generate the same random graph, but you should be using [`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom) (instead of [`RandomSeed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomSeed))!

At any rate, one idea is to annotate the [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) with tooltips, and then look at the rendered graphics to see whether the vertices and labels intersect the rectangle of interest. The following code executes this idea:

```
extractParts[g_, rectangle_] := Cases[
    Show @ Graph[
        g,
        VertexLabels->Placed["Name",{Automatic,Tooltip}],
        EdgeLabels->Placed["Name",Tooltip]
    ],
    Tooltip[a_,label_] /; regionQ[a,rectangle] :> label,
    Infinity
]

regionQ[t_,rectangle_] := !MatchQ[
    RegionIntersection[rectangle, toRegion[t]],
    EmptyRegion[2]
]

toRegion[t_] := First@Cases[t, p_Disk|p_Arrow :> iRegion[p], Infinity]

iRegion[Disk[a__]] := Disk[a]
iRegion[Arrow[BezierCurve[a_], _]] := Line[BezierFunction[a]/@Subdivide[0, 1, 100]]
iRegion[Arrow[a_, _]] := Line[a]
```

Here I apply `extractParts` to a random graph (using [`SeedRandom`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SeedRandom) so you can also generate the same graph):

```
SeedRandom[8];
g = RandomGraph[{20,50}, VertexLabels->"Name"]
```

[image]

> {1 <-> 4, 1 <-> 7, 1 <-> 9, 1 <-> 10, 1 <-> 15, 2 <-> 8, 3 <-> 8, 6 <-> 8, 
>    7 <-> 8, 8 <-> 11, 10 <-> 17, 1, 8}

**Update**

*(I incorporated @kglr's idea of using `Show[g]` to convert a [`Graph`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graph) object to a [`Graphics`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Graphics) object. I also added support for [`BezierCurve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BezierCurve) arrows)*

```
extractParts[g_, rectangle_] := Cases[
    Show @ Graph[
        g,
        VertexLabels->Placed["Name",{Automatic,Tooltip}],
        EdgeLabels->Placed["Name",Tooltip]
    ],
    Tooltip[a_,label_] /; regionQ[a,rectangle] :> label,
    Infinity
]

regionQ[t_,rectangle_] := !MatchQ[
    RegionIntersection[rectangle, toRegion[t]],
    EmptyRegion[2]
]

toRegion[t_] := First@Cases[t, p_Disk|p_Arrow :> iRegion[p], Infinity]

iRegion[Disk[a__]] := Disk[a]
iRegion[Arrow[BezierCurve[a_], _]] := Line[BezierFunction[a]/@Subdivide[0, 1, 100]]
iRegion[Arrow[a_, _]] := Line[a]
```

Here is a graph with curved edges:

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = RandomGraph[
    {20,50},
    VertexLabels->"Name",
    GraphLayout->"LayeredDigraphEmbedding"
];
rectangle = Rectangle[{1.2,0.2},{2.2,1.2}];
Show[g, Graphics[{Opacity[.4], rectangle}]]
```

[image]

And here is the result of using `extractParts`:

```
extractParts[g, rectangle]
```

> {1 <-> 20, 3 <-> 20}

And, here is a different rectangle:

```
rectangle = Rectangle[{-4, 1}, {-3, 2}];
Show[g, Graphics[{Opacity[.4], rectangle}]]

extractParts[g, rectangle]
```

[image]

> {1 <-> 19, 2 <-> 19, 3 <-> 17, 3 <-> 19, 4 <-> 15, 4 <-> 19, 5 <-> 19,
>     10 <-> 19, 11 <-> 12, 11 <-> 13, 16 <-> 19, 11, 19}